# Return two highest values from calculated value

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have the following tables linked below:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlxDe.png

I want to list all the times a menu item has been selected for the menu items that have the 2 highest values for price per serving. Price per serving is calculated by unit price divided by estimated servings. For each selected item, the itemno, eventid, roomid, delivery time, and unit count should be shown.

The query I have is below:

```
 SELECT M.ITEMNO, S.EVENTID, S.ROOMID, S.DELIVERY_TIME, S.UNIT_COUNT
 FROM MENUITEM M, SELECTEDITEM S
 WHERE MAX(M.UNIT_PRICE / M.EST_SERVINGS);
```

This is the only query I could come up with, and it's nowhere near right.

Comment: As the first step: You must use inner join and no cross join.

Comment: hint - first max a query that returns all items then look at the top two.  Such a query would have no where statement.

Comment: Are you using SQL Server or MySQL?  Please tag your questions appropriately.

Answer (score 1):

First you need to join the tables together.  It is a bit of a guess what the join keys are, but let's say that `ItemNo` is common to both tables.  Then you want to order the rows by your ratio and choose the two highest values:

```
SELECT M.ITEMNO, S.EVENTID, S.ROOMID, S.DELIVERY_TIME, S.UNIT_COUNT
FROM MENUITEM M JOIN
     SELECTEDITEM S
     ON M.ITEMNO = S.ITEMNO
ORDER BY M.UNIT_PRICE / M.EST_SERVINGS DESC
LIMIT 2;
```

The `limit 2` is syntax for MySQL.  In SQL Server, you would use `SELECT TOP 2` instead.

EDIT:

In SQL Server, the syntax is:

```
SELECT TOP 2 M.ITEMNO, S.EVENTID, S.ROOMID, S.DELIVERY_TIME, S.UNIT_COUNT
FROM MENUITEM M JOIN
     SELECTEDITEM S
     ON M.ITEMNO = S.ITEMNO
ORDER BY M.UNIT_PRICE / M.EST_SERVINGS DESC;
```

Comment: Hm, where do you put the SELECT TOP 2? I put it in the select statement but that didn't seem to work. 

I am using SQL Server. Forgot to mention that.